# Implementing Level Sets

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to implement a basic level set program for fluid simulation in C++ and visualize it using SFML, so far I have the following simple program for propagating a circular curve:

https://gist.github.com/BhayanakMoth/da8250c849aeead098a61afbf655fb76

However, I am not sure if this the correct way.

Since I am working with a 128×128 grid, the resolution of the grid might not be enough and as a result tracking the curve at phi(x,y) = 0 is not possible in my current code. To deal with that I have tried defining the boundary like |phi(x,y)| < C, but I am not getting a continuous curve all the time unless the C is 0.6-0.9 which would probably be inaccurate. Is there another way to implement Level Set or how can I improve upon this?